# Can someone help me figure out why only one wheel is spinning?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am attempting to use a code which I have posted below for two wheels. However, when connected to power, only one wheel spins. I am using a 9V battery which is what was suggested so I am not sure why only one wheel spins. When both wheels are connected, the wheel that was originally working stopped spinning.

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>      //SPI library for communication with the nRF24L01+
#include "RF24.h"  //The main library of the nRF24L01+
#include "Wire.h"


RF24 radio (8, 9); // CE,CSN

//Create a pipe addresses for  communication
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;

struct package
{
  int X = 1;
  int Y = 1;
};

typedef struct package Package;
Package pos;

int buttonState;
int spinnerState = false ;
int motora_1 = 3;
int motora_2 = 4;
int motorb_1 = 5;
int motorb_2 = 6;
int spinner = 2;



void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();                    //Start the nRF24 communicate
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);   //Sets the address of the transmitter to which the program will receive data.
  radio.startListening();
  pinMode(motora_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motora_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorb_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorb_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(spinner, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(spinner, LOW);
  delay(100);
}

void loop()
{

  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&pos, sizeof(pos));
    radio.read(&buttonState, sizeof(buttonState));
    Serial.print("X:");
    Serial.print(pos.X);
    Serial.print("      Y");
    Serial.print(pos.Y);
    Serial.print("      buttonState");
    Serial.println(buttonState);
  }

  int xAxis = pos.X;
  int yAxis = pos.Y;
  int forward = map(yAxis, 570, 1024, 0, 255);
  int backward = map(yAxis, 480, 0, 0, 255);
  int right = map(xAxis, 570, 1024, 0, 255);
  int left = map(xAxis, 480, 0, 0, 255);

  if (yAxis > 570) {          // Move Forward
    // Set Motor A forward
    analogWrite(motora_1, forward);
    analogWrite(motora_2, 0);
    // Set Motor B forward
    analogWrite(motorb_1, forward);
    analogWrite(motorb_2, 0);
  } else if (yAxis < 480) {                     //Move Backward
    // Set Motor A backward
    analogWrite(motora_1, 0);
    analogWrite(motora_2, backward);
    // Set Motor B backward
    analogWrite(motorb_1, 0);
    analogWrite(motorb_2, backward);
  } else if (xAxis > 570) {                     // Move Right
    // Set Motor A forward
    analogWrite(motora_1, right);
    analogWrite(motora_2, 0);
    // Set Motor B stop
    analogWrite(motorb_1, 0);
    analogWrite(motorb_2, 0);
  } else if (xAxis < 480) {                     // Move Left
    // Set Motor A stop
    analogWrite(motora_1, 0);
    analogWrite(motora_2, 0);
    // Set Motor B foward
    analogWrite(motorb_1, left);
    analogWrite(motorb_2, 0);
  } else  {     //stop
    // Set Motor A stop
    analogWrite(motora_1, 0);
    analogWrite(motora_2, 0);
    // Set Motor B stop
    analogWrite(motorb_1, 0);
    analogWrite(motorb_2, 0);
  }

  if (buttonState == 0 ) {
    spinnerState = ! spinnerState;
    delay(50);
  }

  if (spinnerState == true) {
    digitalWrite(spinner, HIGH);    //turn On spinner
    delay(100);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(spinner, LOW);      //turn Off spinner
    delay(100);
  }


}
```

Comment: With "9V battery" do you mean the standard 9V block batteries, that are often used in smoke detectors? If yes, please try to use a different power source. These batteries are made for very low power applications, not for driving motors

Comment: A connection diagram would be nice!

Comment: You have `int motora_2 = 4;`  and `analogWrite(motora_2, backward);` and an `arduino-uno` tag.  Pin 4 on the Arduino UNO is not a PWM capable pin.  `analogWrite` basically becomes `digitalWrite` on a 0x80 threshold when you use it with non-PWM pins.  So you have at least one problem in your sketch that can't be identified as *the* problem without *a better description* of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the 9V batery is going to struggle with driving two motors. Change this 9V battery out with another power source.

As @timemage points out in his comment, you are using a PWM command on a non-PWM pin. For the Arduino Uno, the PWM pins are: 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11. Move the wiring and change the code so that it is using pin 9, 10 or 11 instead of pin 4.

It sounds like you are trying to test your hardware setup and your firmware at the same time. It is much easier to test your hardware first and make sure that works as expected before testing your firmware. I suggest writing a simpler program (the simpler the better) that just drives the motors full forward - one at a time and then together. Verify that it works and then change your test program so the motors spin in (full) reverse. Then change your test program so it changes the speed of the motors. Then with known working hardware test your firmware.

Comment: Yeah, it may be helpful for them to break the code down into more functions to make it more testable also.